# DevDocs no longer working

Tags: add-on

Is anyone still using the DevDocs add-on? A recent update of EE to 2.9.2 broke it.

> Call to undefined method Cp::set_variable() in /chroot/home/mydomainhere/cp/expressionengine/third_party/dev_docs/mcp.dev_docs.php on line 125

I thought there was an easy fix for this but can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace

```
    $this->_EE->cp->set_variable('cp_page_title', $current_page->heading);
```

with

```
    $this->_EE->view->cp_page_title =  $current_page->heading;
```